# php datetime output issue

Tags: php, datetime

I fetch `datetime` in the DB from different columns based on some conditions.

The script in PHP:

```
if($obj->acct_status == 2)
    $dt = date('d M, Y h:i:s A', strtotime($obj->approve_datetime));

if($obj->acct_status == 4)
    $dt = date('d M, Y h:i:s A', strtotime($obj->suspend_datetime));
```

The DB stores `datetime` in this format:

```
2016-11-11 14:26:03
```

The output:

```
30 Nov, -0001 12:00:00 AM
```

What is the cause of this issue?

Comment: see this http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters

Comment: its because different default format between database and sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly believe `strtotime()` should be avoided when there is a format available.

```
$from_format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$to_format   = 'd M, Y h:i:s A';
$date = '2016-11-11 14:26:03';        


echo DateTime::createFromFormat($from_format, $date)->format($to_format);
```

Outputs:

```
11 Nov, 2016 02:26:03 PM
```

---

Why your code fails I cannot say for certain, it *works* fine here but you can diagnose a little. I'm assuming in your case its because `strtotime()` fails converting, returning `-62169984000` which is actually `0000-00-00 00:00:00` but due to a second, minute, day and a month that is not allowed to be `0`, calculations occur resulting in `0000-00-00 00:00:00` minus 1 day and 1 month, etc being `30 Nov -0001 12:00:00` so it would appear your `$obj->suspend_datetime` does not contain the correct data.

---

I've written 2 small functions to share that would make this whole ordeal easier to handle:

```
function strtodatetime($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'){
  return ($d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date)) && $d->format($format) == $date ? $d : false;
}

function strtounixtime($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'){
  return ($d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date)) && $d->format($format) == $date ? $d->getTimestamp() : 0;
}

echo ($dt = strtodatetime($date)) ? $dt->format($to_format) : 'invalid format';
echo date('d M, Y h:i:s A', strtounixtime($obj->approve_datetime));
```

In your scenario, using `strtounixtime()` (a better `strtotime()`) it would translate back to the unix epoch if it fails.

Comment: Can have many reasons, your code actually works here. I'm assuming `strtotime()` fails in your case. Try echoing its integer and use [this](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) to check if its the correct date.

Comment: Its a good approach but if you change you date with `$date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';` You will get the same output as the above question mention so why use this?

Comment: You can suggest how to validate date supplied before converting :)